# Dyadic rationals representation in the computer memory.

Tags: numerical-methods, binary

So I know what a dyadic rational is and that is represented with a finite number of binary digits in memory. 
The idea is that I want an explanation why is it represented in this way ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The dyadic rationals consist of all rational numbers whose denominators are powers of two.  These are precisely the numbers with base two expansions that terminate in a finite time. These numbers are closed under +, *, and under positive integer powers.  Depending on a machine's floating-point archetecture, they can be represented exactly as as floating point numbers. There is, of course, a limit on the magnitude and the length of dyadic rationals that get represented exactly.